# SQLAlchemy: JSON_ARRAY_APPEND?

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy

I need to update a `JSON` type column in a `MySQL` database using `JSON_ARRAY_APPEND`. I can't just use python's `.append()` because this operation needs to occur on the database level to avoid race conditions.

Is this possible to do with SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use database builtin functions thanks to `func`:

```py
from sqlalchemy import func

func.json_array_append(...)
```

Comment: sweet, thank you!